# is_node and is_edge columns in sys.tables in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, system, rdbms

Can anyone explain the meaning of is_node and is_edge columns in SQL Server sys.tables? What's their point and why are they used? What parameter do they describe? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: They're used by Graph Databases: [Graph processing with SQL Server and Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The metadata for graph tables is specifically described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture#metadata).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes and Edges are fundamental parts for Graph Databases. Graph databases do the same things as relational ones only their structure is different. This differences sometimes make object relations easier to construct. Graph DBs have two types of tables: node and edge. Also, Graph DBs can be managed using RDBMS. *is_node* and *is_edge* columns in sys.tables in SQL Server are to show whether selected table is a node type table or edge type table.